# Movie about two sisters, one of them is professional killer

Tags: identify-this-movie

It's a movie about two sisters, one of them is professional killer. At the start of the movie the killer one meets with a man and his guards and she kill the guards with guns and the main guy protects himself and she killed him with gas (I remember he was in a place that bullets can't affect him so she put her glasses and then the glasses start to make gas which suffocates him).

It's kind of an old movie, the sisters are Japanese or Chinese, I am not sure, but they are from the East, I am sure it's not after 2006 and perhaps in the 90's. I will be thankful if anyone recognizes this. Sorry for bad English guys.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like [So Close](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0300620/combined) (Xi yang tian shi) from 2002:

> A conflict of interest between two high-kicking assassin sisters is complicated as they're pursued by the criminals who hired them and an equally high-kicking female cop.

One of the sisters kills a guy in the start in the manner you've described, with cyanide hidden in a pair of sunglasses. Here's the trailer:

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Movie you've described is [Zatoichi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0363226).

Comment: One liners are not considered good answers. Please elaborate or add plot why do you think it is the same movie. Visit [How to write a good answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and help center for more details.. Please register and become an active user.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.